# Create a php menu that highlights current tab

Tags: php, html, css, menu

So I have a menu in a php file that looks like this (This is the whole file. I'm totally new to PHP.)

menu.php:

```
<li id="current"><a href="#"><span>Home</span></a></li> 
<li><a href="http://blog.me.net/"><span>Blog</span></a></li> 
<li><a href="http://www.me.net/R"><span>Results</span></a></li> 
<li><a href="http://www.me.net/P"><span>Pictures</span></a></li> 
<li><a href="http://www.me.net/O.html"><span>Our Location</span></a></li>
```

Now in my pages I do this (index.php):

```
<div id="tabs1" >
    <ul>
        <!-- CSS Tabs -->
        <?php include("menu.php"); ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So what I want to be able to do is change the line above to this:

```
<?php include("menu.php?current=pictures"); ?>
```

Which would make the active tab the Pictures tab. How can I do this?

Comment: It might be better to leave `include("menu.php");` and then in `index.php` pass the parameter `?current=pictures` through the URL and then use the variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could also try this:

Your `php` script

```
<?php
    $selected = "pictures";
    $current_id = ' id="current"';
    include "menu.php";
?>
```

this is your menu:

```
<ul>
<li <?php if ($selected == "pictures") print $current_id; ?>><a href="#"><span>Home</span></a></li> 
<li <?php if ($selected == "blog") print $current_id; ?>><a href="http://blog.me.net/"><span>Blog</span></a></li> 
<li <?php if ($selected == "home") print $current_id; ?>><a href="http://www.me.net/R"><span>Results</span></a></li> 
<li <?php if ($selected == "me") print $current_id; ?>><a href="http://www.me.net/P"><span>Pictures</span></a></li> 
<li <?php if ($selected == "contacts") print $current_id; ?>><a href="http://www.me.net/O.html"><span>Our Location</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<li <?php if($_GET['current'] == 'home') {echo 'id="current"'}?>><a href="#"><span>Home</span></a></li> 
<li <?php if($_GET['current'] == 'blog') {echo 'id="current"'}?>><a href="http://blog.me.net/"><span>Blog</span></a></li> 
<li <?php if($_GET['current'] == 'results') {echo 'id="current"'}?>><a href="http://www.me.net/R"><span>Results</span></a></li></li>
and so on....
```

Comment: It's not working for some reason. I did it exactly like you said.

Comment: @Bob: is your current value coming from query string eg when you visit blog page, visit it like this blog.php?current=blog

Answer (score 2):

worth looking at

[intelligent navigation](http://www.cssnewbie.com/intelligent-navigation/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<nav>
   <style>
      #active{
        color:#FFC801;
      }
   </style>
   <?php
      $activePage = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], ".php");
      ?>
   <ul>
      <li><a href="about.php" id="<?= ($activePage == 'about') ? 'active':''; ?>">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="mentors.php" id="<?= ($activePage == 'mentors') ? 'active':''; ?>">Mentors</a></li>
      <li><a href="tours.php" id="<?= ($activePage == 'tours') ? 'active':''; ?>">Tours</a></li>
      <li><a href="animation.php" id="<?= ($activePage == 'animation') ? 'active':''; ?>">Animation</a></li>
      <li><a href="blogs.php" id="<?= ($activePage == 'blogs') ? 'active':''; ?>">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="testimonials.php" id="<?= ($activePage == 'testimonials') ? 'active':''; ?>">Testimonials</a></li>
      <li><a href="press_media.php" id="<?= ($activePage == 'press_media') ? 'active':''; ?>">Press/Media</a></li>
      <li><a href="facts.php" id="<?= ($activePage == 'facts') ? 'active':''; ?>">Facts</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation as to how you resolved the asked question.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think its necessary for it to be done at the server side (using up CPU cycles).

Use javascript/CSS to achieve this.

Comment: One reason to use a server-side solution is that some browsers, such as those run on slow cell phones might struggle with the javascript.