# What is the simplest way to add a class to highlight the selected menu with PHP?

Tags: php, css, menu, highlight

I have a menu like this in all pages and want to add a CSS class to highlight the selected menu according to the page.

Which is the **simplest** way to do this?

```
<div id="menu">
   <a href="index.php" class="item-menu">Home</a>
   <a href="projects.php" class="item-menu">Projects</a>   
   <a href="contact.php" class="item-menu">Contact</a>            
</div>
```

The menu code is inside a file called `menu.php` that is called in all pages. I can achieve what I want with a tortuous way (with IFs or another stuff), but I'm searching for a simples solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a php menu that highlights current tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216453/create-a-php-menu-that-highlights-current-tab)

Comment: Simple solutions involve a configuration (often an array containing the data) and then outputting that array. As you have not shared any PHP code, this question can not be answered in a well manner. But the question "what have you tried?" remains so far as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is dirty but pretty easy:

```
<div id="menu">
   <a href="index.php" class="item-menu<?php if( basename( $_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"] ) == 'index.php' ) echo ' active';?>">Home</a>
   <a href="projects.php" class="item-menu<?php if( basename( $_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"] ) == 'projects.php' ) echo ' active';?>">Projects</a>   
   <a href="contact.php" class="item-menu<?php if( basename( $_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"] ) == 'contact.php' ) echo ' active';?>">Contact</a>            
</div>
```

Comment: Just a heads up, this won't work, if this file is included into the index.php, project.php, or contact.php files, as the basename will be the name of the navigation file being included

Comment: To shorten this, you could also wrap it into a function: `function highlight_if($site){ if( basename(__FILE__) == $site . '.php' ) echo ' active'; } ?>`. The link then should look like this: `<a href="index.php" class="item-menu<?php highlight_if('index'); ?>">Home</a>`.

Comment: @BryanMoyles Yeah, he added that info after my answer. $_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"] should be used instead of __FILE__ constant.

Answer (score 1):

This should help get you started

```
<div id="menu">
    <a href="index.php" class="item-menu <?= $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'] == '/index.php' ? 'selected' : '' ?>">Home</a>
    <a href="projects.php <?= $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'] == '/projects.php' ? 'selected' : '' ?>" class="item-menu">Projects</a>   
    <a href="contact.php <?= $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'] == '/contact.php' ? 'selected' : '' ?>" class="item-menu">Contact</a>            
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the solutions already presented, you could simply add a class to the main `<ul/>` element, then set up your CSS for each combination:

```
<div id="menu" class="home">
   <a href="index.php" class="home item-menu">Home</a>
   <a href="projects.php" class="projects item-menu">Projects</a>   
   <a href="contact.php" class="contact item-menu">Contact</a>            
</div>​

#menu.home a.home,
#menu.projects a.projects,
#menu.contact a.contact {
    /* Active link CSS */
}​
```

You would then just need to use PHP to determine the class for `#menu`. This could be done several different ways depending on how your application is set up. If your `menu.php` is simply being include in other pages, you could put this class elsewhere (like on the `<body/>` element) and adjust the previous CSS to something like `body.home #menu a.home, ...`.

See a working example - http://jsfiddle.net/jaredhoyt/7TX4h/

Answer (score 0):

Get the element according to your decision and add the classname to the class attribute:

```
if ($res = $xpath->query(sprintf('//a[@href="%s"]', basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])))
{
    $res->item(0)->setAttribute('class', $res->item(0)->getAttribute('class') . ' active');
}
```

This assumes you have the menu inside a dom element and you've to a `DOMXpath` available for it (`$xpath`).