# redirect to specific tab in laravel using bootstrap v4

Tags: php, laravel, controller, tabs, bootstrap-4

I have been trying to redirect the user to the same tab he was in using Laravel and Bootstrap v4.

For example, if the user create a treatment from the treatments tab, I want him to be redirected back to the same tab which is "treatments"

Please find below the code I'm using for tab navigation.

```
<div class="card ">
<div class="card-header">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs card-header-tabs pull-right"  id="myTab" role="tablist">
   <li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link active" id="treatments-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#treatments" role="tab" aria-controls="treatments" aria-selected="true"><i class="fas fa-tooth fa-fw"></i> Dental Treatments</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="companies-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#companies" role="tab" aria-controls="companies" aria-selected="false"><i class="fas fa-building fa-fw"></i> Insurance Companies</a>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="card-body">
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="treatments" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="treatments-tab">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="companies" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="companies-tab">...</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I have tried to follow these two methods, none have worked.

https://medium.com/@grmcameron/redirect-to-a-specific-tab-in-laravel-149398a9e655

[Redirect back to a specific tab pane in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33747262/redirect-back-to-a-specific-tab-pane-in-laravel)

tried to send a message that contains a specific word from the controller to the blade it didn't work too.

Could you please explain how to achieve this?

Thanks,
Jake

Comment: are you using ajax ?

Comment: Nope. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to give the id attribute of each tab. Call the id of specific tab in url every time. e.g. url#companies

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    if(location.hash) {
        $('a[href=' + location.hash + ']').tab('show');
    }
      $(document.body).on("click", "a[data-toggle]", function(event) {
          location.hash = this.getAttribute("href");
      });


      $(".clickable-row").click(function() {
            window.location = $(this).data("href");
        });


    });
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer. However, I only gave you just two tabs, my page contains around 8 tabs, if I want to implement your answer I'm gonna have multiple rows of the same code but the only difference is the "active" in the class. Is there a more better way to do it? Again, I really appreciate the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You can also try this one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216453/create-a-php-menu-that-highlights-current-tab

Comment: The thing is, you just have to pass a segment in url to identify the current tab. I also stuck many times on this material. Jquery or JavaScript are also a good way to tackle this but sometimes they disturb the functionality due to conflicts.

Comment: I have edited my answer. I hope this will be useful because i have also used it in my project.